# Swift: How to filter array of object by needed amount of value?

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I am having a class like this:

```
class JobMembers {
    
    var key: String?
    let memberJob: String?
    let memberName: String?
    let memberID:String?
    let normalPrice:Double?
    var sumFreelanceRating:Double!
    let priceJPerfScore:Double?
    
        
    
    init(sumFreelanceRating:Double, normalPrice:Double, memberJob: String, memberName: String, priceJPerfScore:Double, memberID:String) {
            
        self.sumFreelanceRating = sumFreelanceRating
        self.normalPrice = normalPrice
        self.memberName = memberName
        self.memberJob = memberJob
        self.priceJPerfScore = priceJPerfScore
        self.memberID = memberID
  
        }
    
    
    var dictValue: [String: Any] {
        
        return ["memberName" : memberName,
                "memberJob" : memberJob,
                "normalPrice": normalPrice,
                "sumFreelanceRating" : sumFreelanceRating,
                "priceJPerfScore": priceJPerfScore,
                "memberID": memberID]
    }
   
}
```

and initialise an Array and populate it for testing purposes like this:

```
var freelancerArray = [JobMembers]()

var member1JP = JobMembers(sumFreelanceRating: 35.6, normalPrice: 4.4, memberJob: "Tennis", memberName: "Aggazzi", priceJPerfScore: 2.2, memberID: "-FG84832iMV0Seznf-D" )

var member2JP = JobMembers(ajp: 2.3, crea: 3.4, ijr: 4.5, qpa: 5.6, coj: 6.7, los: 1.3, iracc: 2.4, dph: 4.8, sumFreelanceRating: 31.0, normalPrice: 6.84, memberJob: "Fussball", memberName: "Mueller", priceJPerfScore: 172.0, memberID: "-MA6VScOQiMV0Seznf-D")

var member3JP = JobMembers(sumFreelanceRating: 41.9, normalPrice: 5.5, memberJob: "Fussball", memberName: "Schweinsteiger", priceJPerfScore: 140.0, memberID: "-FF6666QiMV0Seznf-D")

var member4JP = JobMembers(sumFreelanceRating: 38.7, normalPrice: 3.3, memberJob: "Tennis", memberName: "Federer", priceJPerfScore: 170.0, memberID: "-FA874506QiMV0Seznf-D")

var member5JP = JobMembers(sumFreelanceRating: 36.7, normalPrice: 5.3, memberJob: "Tennis", memberName: "Becker", priceJPerfScore: 125.0, memberID: "-FE3454506QiMV0Seznf-D")

var member6JP = JobMembers(sumFreelanceRating: 32.5, normalPrice: 4.4, memberJob: "Tennis", memberName: "Williams", priceJPerfScore: 4.2, memberID: "-ADE3344506QiMV0Seznf-D")

var member7JP = JobMembers(sumFreelanceRating: 37.6, normalPrice: 2.8, memberJob: "Fussball", memberName: "Woods", priceJPerfScore: 5.8, memberID: "-GHI4564506QiMV0Seznf-D")

var member8JP = JobMembers(sumFreelanceRating: 36.6, normalPrice: 4.4, memberJob: "Golf", memberName: "Spieth", priceJPerfScore: 4.4, memberID: "-FGI4564506QiMV0Seznf-D")

var member9JP = JobMembers(sumFreelanceRating: 28.09, normalPrice: 2.8, memberJob: "Skate", memberName: "Dixon", priceJPerfScore: 2.8, memberID: "-4204564506QiMV0Seznf-D")
freelancerArray.append(member1JP)
freelancerArray.append(member2JP)
freelancerArray.append(member3JP)
freelancerArray.append(member4JP)
freelancerArray.append(member5JP)
freelancerArray.append(member6JP)
freelancerArray.append(member7JP)
freelancerArray.append(member8JP)
freelancerArray.append(member9JP)
```

I have another class which represents the users choice of how many `members`he needs from a specific `memberJob`:

```
class JobAmount {
    var key: String?
    let jobName: String?
    let jobAmount: Int?
    
    init(jobName: String, jobAmount: Int) {
        self.jobName = jobName
        self.jobAmount = jobAmount
    }
    var dictValue: [String: Any] {
    
    return ["jobName" : jobName,
            "jobAmount" : jobAmount ]
        
    }
}
```

For testing purposes I populated an array like this:

```
var jobsNeeded:[JobAmount] = []

var jobNeeded1 = JobAmount(jobName: Tennis, jobAmount:3)
var jobNeeded2 = JobAmount(jobName: Fussball, jobAmount2
```

**What do I want to achieve with this?**

The goal should be to fill an array which has the following requirements:

- For the required `jobAmount` of the respective `JobNames`, add the `members` in a new array which has the highest value of `sumFreelanceRating` for the required `JobName`.

**My approach so far**

I tried different solutions from this forum, looked up the swift documentations etc. but couldn't find a proper solution that fits for me.

I am assuming that a good way to go is:

**(1)** sort the `freelancerArray`like follow:
 `freelancerArray.sort(by: {$0.sumFreelanceRating > $1.sumFreelanceRating})`

**(2)** Filter the `freelancerArray`in a `temporaryArray`containing only the objects for the specific `memberJob`

**(3)** Append the number of needed values in a final Array (`for i in 0..<jobName.jobAmount`, something like `JobRequirementArray`, where all the `members`which are needed get stored.

For Step **2** and **3** it must be obviously done for every `memberJob` the User needs.
Which and how many `memberJobs`it is going to be is unknown in advance.

**Edit Pursued outcome:**

`let finalJobsneeded:[JobMembers]()`

Then the array should contain following JobMembers:

`finalJobsneeded = [member1JP, member3JP, member4JP, member5JP, member7JP]`

As you can see, we need 5 Members in total, whereby 2 of them must contain the `memberJob: Fussball`and also have the highest value of `sumFreelanceRating` for all alternatives of `memberJob: Fussball`. The other 3 Members should contain the `memberJob: Tennis`and also have the highest value for all alternatives of `memberJob: Tennis`

I hope my explanation of my little Problem was clear enough and someone could help me bringing my ideas into actual code!

Thanks for your help everyone :)

Comment: Yeah true that! I tried something, so I changed it as a String. Will change it. 

I didn't show sample data, since I didn't want to overload the question! 

I will change my question and hope you can work with that then! :)

Comment: Unrelated but it's pointless to declare properties as optional which are clearly initialized with non-optional values. Surprisingly the code compiles also without the question marks. And do you really need *classes*?

Comment: I don't need classes! Structures are also okay. 
The goal is the goal ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a dictionary to hold the selected elements

```
var selected = [String: [JobMembers]]()
```

Then use a `forEach` loop to filter out the members with the right job name. Since this is done per job we can at the same time sort and select only the required number.

```
jobsNeeded.forEach { job in
    selected[job.jobName, default: []].append(contentsOf:
        freelancerArray
            .filter { job.jobName == $0.memberJob}
            .sorted { member1, member2 in member1.sumFreelanceRating > member2.sumFreelanceRating}
            .prefix(job.jobAmount)
    )
}
```

If you want all members in one array you can use `flatMap` on the dictionary values

```
let selectedMembers = selected.values.flatMap({$0})
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is trying to achieve the same.
This works for me now!

```
func tryToGetIt() {
 var temp1: [JobMembers] = []
    for jobAmount in jobAmountArray{
        temp1 = freelancerArray.filter { $0.memberJob == jobAmount.jobName}
        temp1.sort(by: {$0.sumFreelanceRating > $1.sumFreelanceRating})
        for value in temp1{
            print("temp1: ")
            print(value.memberName as Any)
        }
        let neededValue = jobAmount.jobAmount
        print("needed Value: ", neededValue as Any, "for Job: ", jobAmount.jobName as Any)
        let deletValue = temp1.count - neededValue!
        print("delet Value: ", deletValue)
        temp1.remove(0..<deletValue)
        
        for member in temp1 {
            print("memberName: ", member.memberName as Any, "memberJob: ", member.memberJob as Any, "memberID: ", member.memberID  as Any, "memberJP: " as Any, member.sumFreelanceRating as Any)
        }
        print(temp1.count)
        
            
        for value in temp1 {
            finalBest.append(value)
        }
        
        print("\n \n")
    }
    for member in finalBest {
        print("memberName: ", member.memberName as Any, "memberJob: ", member.memberJob  as Any, "memberID: " as Any, member.memberID as Any, "memberJP: ", member.sumFreelanceRating as Any)
        print(finalBest.count)
    }
    print("final Best: ", finalBest)
    print("final Best amount: ", finalBest.count)
}
```

Comment: What is `WeighScore` and where is `finalBest` declared?

Comment: Sorry ```WeighScore```was an old name, now changed it to the one in my initial question!. finalBest is just an Array of ```var finalBest = [JobMembers]()```, where I am storing the output outside of the function